# How to be featured on "Who's using Node-RED?" section on its website?

Tags: node-red

I would like to know how can my company be featured on the "Who's using Node-RED?" section of its website. The link below it takes us to a dead end where I could not find any information about it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The link works just fine and points at the top of the page to the 2 places where you could raise this, either on the Node-RED forum or the Node-RED Slack channel.

Comment: You can also send an email to team@nodered.org